# node Notworking properly

Tags: node.js, node-modules

hai guys after learning infosys springboard i used npm config set registry https://infyartifactory.ad.infosys.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm this command after this command i am not not able to use my node properly, am not able to install any module.
please help....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD9HE.png)

solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.